# Error when Adding ASP.net Update panels dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

A trying to add `UpdatePanels` dynamically to a page, but whenever I run the code I get an exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Extensions.dll`, I Started getting this error after adding the controls to an `UpdatePanel`, The code works fine when I add the controls in a panel but I need the update panel for later .

```
private void loadCandidates()
{
    try
    {
        sql = "exec dbo.spLoadCandidates @NationalID, @PostID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalID", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label myLabel = new Label();
                ImageButton myImage = new ImageButton();

                myImage.OnClientClick = "ImageClick1(this);";
                UpdatePanel myPanel = new UpdatePanel();

                RadioButton myRadioButton = new RadioButton();
                candidates.Add(myRadioButton);

                myImage.ImageUrl = "Handler4.ashx?ID=" + reader["IDNo"].ToString();


                myRadioButton.GroupName = "Candidates";
                myRadioButton.ID = reader["CID"].ToString();
                myRadioButton.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                myPanel.Controls.Add(myPanel); //add the panel to the placeholder
                myPanel.Controls.Add(myImage);
                myPanel.Controls.Add(myLabel);
                myPanel.Controls.Add(myRadioButton); //add the radiobutton to the panel

                AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                trigger.EventName = "Click";
                trigger.ControlID = myImage.UniqueID;
                UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have mistake here --> myPanel.Controls.Add(myPanel);

Comment: You really should make your command type be StoredProcedure and drop the "exec".